# How to set correctly utf8 on oracle?

Tags: oracle

I check my db,and seems to be UTF8 complaint

```
select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';

PARAMETER        |VALUE
NLS_CHARACTERSET |AL32UTF8
```

But when i do a search on a VIEW

```
SQL> select titolo,anno,genere from generale where titolo like  '%Roma dr%' order by titolo;

TITOLO                                                      |ANNO   |GENERE
------------------------------------------------------------|-------|------------
Roma drogata: la polizia non pu?? intervenire               |1975   |Poliziesco

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02
```

The two ?? tell me something is wrong.
Any solution to give a full utf8?Thanks

Comment: That's your SQL client (presumably SQL\*Plus) which cannot _display_ those characters. You need to use a font that can display them and in case of SQL\*Plus you also need to switch the command line from which you start SQL\*Plus to UTF-8 (I _think_ that is done through `chcp 65001`)

Comment: I'm on unix,i had try LANG="utf8" and LANG="it_IT.utf8" but no success,of course those variables were exported

Comment: I have set export NLS_LANG=Italian_ITALY.UTF8
now speak italian,but still ?? instead of ò

Comment: What do you get by `locale charmap`?

Comment: it's all it_IT.utf8

Comment: Can you try this: `SELECT DUMP(titolo, 1016), ASCIISTR(titolo), UNISTR('\00F2') FROM generale WHERE titolo LIKE 'Roma drogata%;`

Comment: Return this Typ=1 Len=49 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 52,6f,6d,61,20,64,72,6f,67,61,74,61,3a,20,6c,61,20,70,6f,6c,69,7a,69,61,20,6e,6f,6e,20,70,75,ef,bf,bd,ef,bf,bd,20,69,6e,74,65,72,76,65,6e,69,72,65
Roma drogata: la polizia non pu\FFFD\FFFD intervenire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your reply of

```
SELECT ASCIISTR(titolo) FROM generale WHERE titolo LIKE 'Roma drogata%;

TITOLO                                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------
Roma drogata: la polizia non pu\FFFD\FFFD intervenire
```

You get `Roma drogata: la polizia non pu?? intervenire` because it has been inserted wrong into your database, i.e. when the record was inserted the client had set `NLS_LANG` wrong.

Unicode character U+FFFD is this one: [REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](https://codepoints.net/U+FFFD)

Probably the SQL script was saved as UTF-8 but `NLS_LANG` was set to ISO-8859-1 or Windows-Cp1252 or similar.